# Function series with the "rand" function (Matlab)

Tags: matlab, random

I am writing a code for a sum of functions, where each iteration is slightly changed with a random number:

```
S1 = symsum((exp(10i*n*(1+0.01*rand)*sin(x))),n,0,19)
```

I use symsum because this appeares the best choice for function series. However, the result graphs that I get look too neat and I suspect that rand works only once for the whole sum, Is it the case? and if yes, how to fix this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you please add more details to your code? symbols definitions and graph plotting (a minimum viable code!)

Comment: yes, ´rand´ works only once since you are also calling it only once (before calling ´symsum´ on the result). Please provide the whole code to reproduce your example. In general, you will need to find a way to invoke ´rand´ at every point of summation but as this is symbolic math, this might be difficult